# c# - best way to iterate through all rows in a datarepeater?

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

```
private void exam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCount();

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; password =; database = dbtest1;");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT question, question_no, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4 from quiz_tions where quiz_id = '" + lid + "' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " + count + ";", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        label5.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "question");
        label6.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "question_no");
        rb1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "choice1");
        rb2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "choice2");
        rb3.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "choice3");
        rb4.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "choice4");
        dataRepeater1.DataSource = dt;

        LoadData();


        label1.Text = qtitle;
        label3.Text = qtype;
    }
```

I have a `DataRepeater` control on my form which is populated using the code above. Every time this code is executed . . .

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRepeaterItem c in dataRepeater1.Controls)
        {
            ss += ((Label)c.Controls["label5"]).Text + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(ss);
        ss = "";
    }
```

It gives me different results when I click different rows before clicking the button (sometimes 3 lines, sometimes 4 lines) and it's not always correct cause I have 5 rows on my `DataRepeater` control when I execute that. Why is this happening? What's the proper way to iterate through the rows of `DataRepeater`?

P.S. Another problem (maybe) unrelated to my post is that whenever I scroll down/up on the `DataRepeater`, sometimes it auto-checks a random `RadioButton` in the list. What's wrong with this control?

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: Are you sure `label5.Text` is not empty in some repeater items?

Comment: Yes, they're not empty.

Comment: `ss` is a `TextBox` type? If yes try `...+ "\r\n"` instead `...+"\n"`

Comment: `ss` is a `Global string`, and your posted answer below still doesn't work. I think the problem is with the `DataRepeater`.

Comment: So if it global variable how you counting these lines? _sometimes 3 lines, sometimes 4 lines_ how do you know  there are 3 or 5 lines? What you exactly want to do?

Comment: `foreach (DataRepeaterItem c in dataRepeater1.Controls) { ss += ((Label)c.Controls["label5"]).Text + "\n"; }MessageBox.Show(ss);` this must return 5 lines of text in a `MessageBox`, but it doesn't,

Answer (score 1):

If You using `TextBox` multiline you should use `\r\n` instead `\n`

> Windows text boxes need CRLF as line terminators, not just LF.

You can use `\r\n`

```
 ss += ((Label)c.Controls["label5"]).Text + "\r\n";
```

or `System.Environment.NewLine`

```
ss += ((Label)c.Controls["label5"]).Text  + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

or `StringBuilder`

```
 var sb = new StringBuiler();
 foreach (DataRepeaterItem c in dataRepeater1.Controls)
 {
    sb.AppendLine(((Label)c.Controls["label5"]).Text);
 }

 ss+= sb;
```

Comment: Use trim to remove any extra characters. ((Label)c.Controls["label5"]).Text.Trim();